# Setup complex mach message header

Tags: c, macos, ipc, mach

I'm trying to setup a mach message for sending a string out of line using mach IPC. However I get an `(ipc/send) invalid msg-header` error when trying to send the out of line message.

Here's the message structure.

```
struct ool_msg
{
    mach_msg_header_t header;
    mach_msg_body_t body;
    mach_msg_ool_descriptor_t data;
    mach_msg_type_number_t count;
};
```

I'm setting up the header like this. The variable `msg` below is a `struct ool_msg`.

```
hdr = &(msg.header);
hdr->msgh_bits = MACH_MSGH_BITS_LOCAL(MACH_MSG_TYPE_COPY_SEND);
hdr->msgh_bits |= MACH_MSGH_BITS_COMPLEX;
hdr->msgh_size = sizeof(msg);
hdr->msgh_local_port = MACH_PORT_NULL;
hdr->msgh_remote_port = port;
```

This is how I setup up the rest of the Mach message.

```
msg.body.msgh_descriptor_count = 1;
msg.data.address = string;
msg.data.size = strlen(string) + 1;
msg.data.deallocate = FALSE;
msg.data.copy = MACH_MSG_VIRTUAL_COPY;
msg.data.type = MACH_MSG_OOL_DESCRIPTOR;
msg.count = msg.data.size;
```

So how do I correctly setup the message header for OOL Mach IPC?

## Edit

Here's a program that reproduces my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>

static char *string = "123456789";

struct ool_msg
{
    mach_msg_header_t header;
    mach_msg_body_t body;
    mach_msg_ool_descriptor_t data;
    mach_msg_type_number_t count;
};

int main(void)
{
    kern_return_t err;
    struct ool_msg msg;
    mach_msg_header_t *hdr;
    mach_port_t port = MACH_PORT_NULL;

    err = mach_port_allocate(mach_task_self(), MACH_PORT_RIGHT_RECEIVE, &port);
    if(err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        mach_error("Can't allocate mach port\n", err);
        return (-1);
    }

    err = mach_port_insert_right(mach_task_self(), port, port,
                                 MACH_MSG_TYPE_MAKE_SEND);
    if(err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        mach_error("Can't insert port right\n", err);
        return (-1);
    }

    hdr = &(msg.header);
    hdr->msgh_bits = MACH_MSGH_BITS_LOCAL(MACH_MSG_TYPE_COPY_SEND);
    hdr->msgh_bits |= MACH_MSGH_BITS_COMPLEX;
    hdr->msgh_size = sizeof(msg);
    hdr->msgh_local_port = MACH_PORT_NULL;
    hdr->msgh_remote_port = port;

    msg.body.msgh_descriptor_count = 1;
    msg.data.address = string;
    msg.data.size = strlen(string) + 1;
    msg.data.deallocate = FALSE;
    msg.data.copy = MACH_MSG_VIRTUAL_COPY;
    msg.data.type = MACH_MSG_OOL_DESCRIPTOR;
    msg.count = msg.data.size;

    err = mach_msg(hdr,
                  MACH_SEND_MSG,
                  hdr->msgh_size,
                  0,
                  MACH_PORT_NULL,
                  MACH_MSG_TIMEOUT_NONE,
                  MACH_PORT_NULL);
    if(err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        mach_error("Can't send mach msg\n", err);
        return (-1);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to send the string? Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @JoshdeKock I added an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/gnumach-doc/Message-Format.html) state:

> `MACH_MSGH_BITS_REMOTE` and `MACH_MSGH_BITS_LOCAL` macros return the
>   appropriate `mach_msg_type_name_t` values, given a `msgh_bits` value. The
>   `MACH_MSGH_BITS` macro constructs a value for `msgh_bits`, given two
>   `mach_msg_type_name_t` values.

So you need to use the `MACH_MSGH_BITS` macro rather than the `MACH_MSGH_BITS_LOCAL` macro when setting the `mach_msg_header_t.msgh_bits`. Otherwise you are setting it to a `mach_msg_type_name_t` as opposed to the `msgh_bits` which is the one you want.

To clarify, you need something like the following piece of code to get your msgh_bits:

```
hdr->msgh_bits = MACH_MSGH_BITS(MACH_MSG_TYPE_COPY_SEND, MACH_MSG_TYPE_MAKE_SEND)
```